# osslsigncode Sign with Hardware Token issue (Failed to set 'dynamic' engine)

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11, openssl-engine, safenet

I'm trying to sign EXE files with osslsigncode, my cert and key are on a Safenet Hardware token which the system is able to read :

:~# pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/pkcs11/libeToken.so --login --list-objects --id 01
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)

**Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
label:      Sectigo_2xxxxxxxxxxxx
subject:    DN: serialNumber=xxxxxxxxx/jurisdictionC=FR/businessCategory=Private Organization, C=FR, ST=xxxxxxxxxxx, O=xxxxx, CN=xxxxxx
serial:     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ID:         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

When I try to sign with osslsigncode with the cert I extracted from the token and pointing on the token for the key I get a :

Failed to set 'dynamic' engine
4069A3092C7F0000:error:1300006D:engine routines:dynamic_load:init failed:../crypto/engine/eng_dyn.c:514:
Failed

Here is the command line :

**osslsigncode sign -pkcs11engine /home/xxxxx/libp11-0.4.12/src/.libs/libpkcs11.so -pkcs11module /usr/lib/pkcs11/libeToken.so -certs /home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx.pem -h sha256 -n test -t http://timestamp.sectigo.com?td=sha256 -key 'pkcs11:model=ID%20Prime%20MD;manufacturer=Gemalto;serial=xxxxxxxxxxx;token=xxxxxx;object=key;type=private' -verbose -in /home/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx.exe -out /home/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.exe**

Did anyone had this kind of issues ?

I'm stuck here :(

Please ask if you need more information.

Thanks

Tried with opensc pkcs11 module (token not recognized). Tried various pkcs11 libraries with the same result.

Comment: Found the issue was related to a bug in osslsigncode v2.5 the fix is to upgrade to 2.6 or downgrade to 2.4

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pkcs11.so`, not `libpkcs11.so` as an engine:

```
osslsigncode sign -pkcs11engine /home/xxxxx/libp11-0.4.12/src/.libs/pkcs11.so -pkcs11module ...
```

Comment: This is not related specificaly to the lib but to the version of osslsigncode I used to have (please see my own comment).

Comment: I've tried several versions of osslsigncode: 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6 with different build types and always got the same error: "Failed to set 'dynamic' engine..."

But when I changed libpkcs11 to pkcs11 it started to work well with version 2.6 on MacOS. 

May be the problem is also in osslsigncode 2.5, I didn't test it with libpkcs11. But libpkcs11 didn't work for be with any on these three versions of osslsigncode.

Comment: The "Failed to set 'dynamic' engine..." error is due to an osslsigncode issue. There's a patch at https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode/issues/316 to work around this (move `ENGINE_finish` calls from `read_token` to end of `main`)